# Making a code box for my website

Tags: html, css

I am making a site that will give some code examples . So, I wish to show with proper indentation and also with different colors if possible.

Can anyone suggest me some way to do it ??

Thanks :)

Comment: http://usejquery.com/posts/1/highlight-your-source-code-with-jquery-and-chili

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) script.

Comment: Hey !! Its working fine , but I am getting a question mark at the top which on clicking shows the details of syntax highlighter and asks to donate. is there any way to remove these links ???

Comment: Finally got a way to remove the qn mark.. It can be done by changing the Z-index of toolbar in css files given. Set it to -10 instead of 10 and the qn mark of SyntaxHighlighter vanishes...:) :)

Comment: @PrashanT: Set `toolbar` to false.  http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way directly.Also you can change it however you want

```
<div style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;"><pre>CODE
 GOES HERE</pre></div>
```

Comment: The `<xmp>` tag has been deprecated for years (since HTML 4.0), use `<pre>` instead.